# Politely asking a teacher I don't get along with to "hurry up"

Tags: teaching, internship

I'm starting an internship as part of my bachelor in Bioinformatics study (in the Netherlands bachelors and masters are sometimes separate) and I have some trouble communicating with my teacher.

Besides his teaching position he also coördinates all the internships of every student. He checks if a student meets the criteria and determines if somebody can start an internship (or not). In order to meet some of these criteria, I must hand in documents he has to review and sign. I'm sure he is very busy but I get the feeling he simply just forgets me or that he doesn't care about me that much and puts approving of my internship on a side-track. He takes quite some time to review things and I realy need to start at the hospital I got a great position at.

A month ago we had an incident that put some strain on our student-teacher relationship. I'm already working in the hospital to define an interesting assignment but did not do any work for the internship itself. Defining an assignment is fine but working on it is not since I do not yet qualify. My teacher has yet to approve of some documents before I can officially start. But due to a miscommunication he thought I already did and got quite upset. Although this issue had been resolved, I still sense some hostility. This also has to do with me being a lazy student in the past. I'm realy turning things around now and found new motivation but I think he is still holding my former self against me. To be fair, he hasn't been able to see my current work ethic yet.

Right now, everybody (myself and the hospital) are waiting for him to sign the final documents and approve of the internship. How do I ask him about the status of my approval without being "pushy"? I realy don't want to strain the relationship any further.

Comment: "...sense some hostility" - maybe you overinterpret here. However, you say "he thought I already did" - did what? Have others been approved and you not? If yes, you may politely ask whether the approval is going through well, as your starting date is <...>. If others haven't been approved either, it would be wiser to let one of your friends/co-students do the asking who has no reason to believe to have a strained relation with the teacher.

Comment: Maybe it is better if your supervisor at the hospital asks him.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Others already got approved but there are no fixed dates on which we must start. I can determine the date myself. The problem is that I keep postponing this date because my teacher seems to be taking his time

Comment: I support @Davidmh's idea. Your teacher may allocate candidates first who are more promising in his eyes. And, to be fair, if he only has seen your not-so-effective side so far, that's a legitimate strategy. Anyway, what intervals of checking are we talking about? Definitely no daily nagging, unless there is a burning deadline.

Comment: There is also the question what time frame we are talking about here, and how much work this reviewing is for the teacher. I sometimes get requests from students that require me to go over some documents and write a 3-page report. For these cases, if the student starts asking for status updates 3 days in, I feel like the student is unreasonably pushy.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: I really try to avoid daily emails/visits. My teacher says he will react in about two days so I check after three or more.
About the timeframe: The current document he has to review is about 3 sheets. The only thing he has to do is check if three things are in order. So he doesn't even has to read the whole thing.

Comment: @Tom Do you have an idea how many "about 3 sheets" document one has to read in his position? ;-) Once you have seen how many, you will appreciate that his brain has gone blurry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go talk to him.

Honestly, go to his office hour to sit down and tell him how important it is for you to start the internship soon and how much you look forward to it. This might also help to alleviate his feeling that you are lazy and let him see that you are now back on track and eager to get involved. Make a point to make it not about him being slow (he might be really busy), but you being eager.

Comment: At the same time, you might want to mention that you know you've been lazy in the past, but you've found new motivation and are making a serious effort to turn things around. This might improve your relationship with him.

Comment: I tried to schedule a meeting after the incident we had to clear the air. However, when he learned it was a misunderstanding he didn't think it was necessary to personally meet. Do you think I have to arrange another meeting because I really like your idea. I've been avoiding personal conversations but showing willingness and some assertiveness is a good plan.